# How do you use "hold on" with MATLAB GUI?

Tags: matlab

I am working with GUIDE to make a big GUI. I would like to plot two sets of data on the same plot.  For regular MATLAB code I would write:

```
time = 1:10;
data1= (1:10).*2;
data2= (1:10).*3;
figure;
plot(t,data1);
hold on;
plot(t,data2);
hold off;
```

However, this does not work with the GUI system. With the GUI I am typing:

```
time = 1:10;
data1= (1:10).*2;
data2= (1:10).*3;
plot(handles.axes1,t,data1);
hold on;
plot(handles.axes1,t,data2);
hold off;
```

But this does not work. data2 just over writes the previous plot. Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

SOLUTION:

```
time = 1:10;
data1= (1:10).*2;
data2= (1:10).*3;
plot(handles.axes1,x,y);
hold(handles.axes1)
plot(handles.axes1,x,z);
```

Comment: You might want to use `plot(t,data1,'Parent',handles.axes1)` and the same for the 2nd plot.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only thing you want to plot, just use plot functions without axes handle (they will have the same handle by default):

```
t = 1:10;
data1= (1:10).*2;
data2= (1:10).*3;
plot(t,data1);
hold on;
plot(t,data2);
hold off;
```